# laying plywood flooring over potential asbestos floor tiles

Tags: flooring, plywood, asbestos

I have removed old carpet in the main bedroom which has exposed potential asbestos containing floor tiles (this is not confirmed but the look of them and age of the house is a strong give away that these may contain asbestos)

Our aim was to lay a floating laminate flooring over the top of the tiles with some underlay, but the floor is uneven with bumps (8-14mm) at 2 separate parts of the room. The bumps seems too large a problem for self-levelling compound.

I would like to use plywood to raise the floor and attempt to minimise the impact of the bumps. But I am not sure how best to set them on top of the floor tiles. I am trying to do this without drilling into the floor below as this will damage the tiles and potential release asbestos fibres in the air.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to fasten the plywood to the framing below, so this isn't a good plan. Tile removal is what I'd be doing. It doesn't need to be thought of as a nightmare if done properly.

Comment: What is the floor under the tiles? I agree with Isherwood that the plywood needs to be secured to the floor but if your have bumps two large for leveling compound is the plywood going to be enough ? A photo would be helpful.

Comment: If the tiles are 9” square they could be asbestos. (They made 9” asphalt tiles too, but most 9” are asbestos.) if they are 12” square, there’s a good chance that they’re not asbestos...but the mastic could contain asbestos.